# Java .csv print statement issue

Tags: java, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, input

Currently working on a project that imports a .csv file(which is 21 rows, 20 columns), captures it into an array and then prints a specific cell within the spreadsheet... Currently running into an issue that causes the output to be 20 rows and one column, of "null" Except the second row in the output seems to be the last row, second column cell from the file. What's going on with the Null and why is it pulling the last row data? Thanks, guys/gals for any input.

```java
public class cvsPull {

    public String[][] myArray;
    String csvFile = "Crime.csv";

    public Class csvPull() {


    myArray = new String[20][20];


    try {
        s = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            int theRow = 1;
            int theCol = 0;
            InputLine = s.nextLine();
            String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");

            for (String InArray1 : InArray) {
                myArray[theRow][theCol] = InArray1;
                theCol++;
                if (theCol==20) {
                   theCol=0;
                   theRow++;
                }
             // System.out.println(myArray[theRow][theCol]);

             }

        } 
        for (String[] theString : myArray) {
            System.out.println(theString[1]);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("incorrect file name" + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the row counter to 1 at the start of every loop:

```
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        int theRow = 1;
        int theCol = 0;
```

This means every row of the file is written to the same place in memory. Also, the first index for rows is 0 just t like for columns, so you'll want to set it to 0 initially:

```
    int theRow = 0;
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        int theCol = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What could be in place of the 
`while (s.hasNext())`
so instead of going through each line and printing, rather just print the single line inputted.

Comment: What do you mean by "single line inputted"? Previously you have said your input file has 21 lines

Comment: It does, I mean printing out just a single line(row) from the csv file rather than the entire first column

Comment: sounds like you want to loop that iterates over the strings (columns) in a given row: `for (String theString : myArray[row]) System.out.println(theString);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using lib to read the CSV file:
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "/Users/mkyong/csv/country3.csv";

        CSVReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            String[] line;
            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Country [id= " + line[0] + ", code= " + line[1] + " , name=" + line[2] + "]");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But what I'm currently doing is storing file data into an array in a separate class from main(). I have no issues using the get method to pull into the main() or importing the file in general. My question is more towards fixing the specific data my code is pulling.